# How to fill backbone collection from JSON

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js-collections

Having the following code:

```
var Tasks = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: 'http://localhost:5000/tasks'
});

var TaskView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '.page',
    render: function() {
        var that = this;
        var tasks = new Tasks();

        tasks.fetch( {
            success: function(tasks) {
                var template = _.template($('#task-list-template').html(), {tasks: tasks.models});

                that.$el.html(template);
            }
        })
    }
});

var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        '' : 'home' // intentionally blank for the home page
    }
});

// Display logic
var taskListView = new TaskView({ });
var router = new Router();

router.on('route:home', function() {
    taskListView.render();
});

Backbone.history.start();
```

The following HTML:

```
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <h1>TODO app</h1>
        <hr />
        <div class="page"></div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/template" id="task-list-template">
        <table class="table striped">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Task</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <% _.each(tasks.tasks, function(task) { %>
            <tr>
                <td><%=task.get('task') %></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <% }); %>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </script>

    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.4.2/underscore-min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/0.9.2/backbone-min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="todoapp.js"></script>

</body>
```

and the following JSON return from an AJAX request:

```
{
  "tasks": [
    {
      "id": 6314025183,
      "task": "1"
    }
  ]
}
```

I was wondering how to fill the Collection with the JSON data. I'm unable to fill my HTML table. I suspect my collection to not being filled properly.

1. How could I validate the content of the collection?
2. I'm I filling the collection the right way?

This code is based on this video from Thomas Davis available on youtube.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FZSjvWtUxYk

Answer (score 3):

You have two problems. One is code related and one is unfortunately API related.

---

The API problem can be solved in two ways, but I'll just lay it out first.

When a `Collection` requests data (from the `url` property) it expects an array of data. Unfortunately your API is returning an object:

```
{
  "tasks": [
    {
      "id": 6314025183,
      "task": "1"
    }
  ]
}
```

This is pretty common in a lot of API design, and really speaks to a general misunderstanding of what makes APIs useful.

You'll notice the data you actually *want* is here in the `tasks` key of the object:

```
[
    {
      "id": 6314025183,
      "task": "1"
    }
]
```

It's an array of task objects, each with an `id` and - what I assume is - a task `id`.

Great, so you have two options here: you can fix the API so that a request to a collection route like `/tasks` returns the collection:

```
[
    {
      "id": 6314025183,
      "task": "1"
    }
]
```

Or, you can use Backbone's `parse` method to hack around the junk data.

From the documentation for [`Collection.parse`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-parse):

> Override this if you need to work with a preexisting API, or better namespace your responses.

Here's a quick example:

```
var Tasks = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    'url': 'http://localhost:5000/tasks',

    'parse': function( apiResponse ){
        return apiResponse.tasks;
    }
});
```

Note the information contained in that parse method that does not have a home. How do I know that the key of the response is `tasks`?

If I'm a new developer coming into this code, the fact is that *I don't*. It's tribal knowledge or knowledge I have to go searching for in the API raw response body. The better solution is to namespace the API response to return the collection as requested.

---

Your second problem is related to your code. In your code you have a `Collection` and a `View` and a template, but in your template, you're treating your tasks like a plain ol' javascript object, using underscore to loop over a key.

Instead, tell your collection how to represent it's data.

A collection is a set of related `Model`s.

```
var Task = Backbone.Model.extend({});
var Tasks = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    'url': 'http://localhost:5000/tasks',
    'model': Task,

    'parse': function( apiResponse ){
        return apiResponse.tasks;
    }
});
```

Now, when you hydrate your collection it will automatically create a model representing each set of discrete data.

You can change your view to look like this:

```
var TaskView = Backbone.View.extend({
    'el': '.page',
    'template': _.template($('#task-list-template').html()),
    'render': function() {
        var that = this;
        var tasks = new Tasks();

        tasks.fetch( {
            success: function() {
                that.$el.html( that.template( { 'tasks': tasks } ) );
             }
        })
    }
});
```

Since all Backbone objects extend underscore in some way or another ([see the docs for the details](http://backbonejs.org/)), you don't need to manually wrap the passed in collection in underscore. In fact, doing so will almost always create errors. Your template can look like this:

```
<html>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <h1>TODO app</h1>
        <hr />
        <div class="page"></div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/template" id="task-list-template">
        <table class="table striped">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Task</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <% tasks.each( function( task ){ %>
            <tr>
                <td><%= task.get( 'task' ) %></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <% }); %>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </script>

    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.4.2/underscore-min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/0.9.2/backbone-min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="todoapp.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

*The solution posted here is untested, but should allow you to make major debugging leaps even if it does not completely solve the problems*